# Searching number of times a string (from file a) occurs in file b. Each string from file a is on a separate line

Tags: python, search

I am a not new in Python but I am not an educated programmer and I use it very often for my work. So sorry in advance for any not elegant coding solutions.

I have a file (.txt) with a unique string on each line. I want to know how many times each string occurs in another file. I build the following, which works as long as I feed the text I want to find "2-177-382":

```
count = 0
with open(Input_file_B) as f:
    for line in f:
        count += line.count("2-177-382")
    print count
```

This results in:

```
Number of times: 19
```

So far so good. When I replace it with a variable it also works.

```
y="2-177-382"
count = 0
with open(Input_file_B) as f:
    for line in f:
        count += line.count(y)
    print count
```

This also works and results also in:

```
Number of times: 19
```

But now I want to fill *y* using a loop with the data extracted from file A, this is where it goes wrong. File A looks like this:

```
1-1-24
1-1-25
1-1-26
1-1-27
14-178-370
5-224-309
5-226-307
2-177-382
```

I show this as an example below (without how I extract it from the other file).

```
total_A = open(Input_file_A,'r')
Data_input_file_A = total_A.readlines()
y = Data_input_file_A[7]
print y
```

Results in:

```
2-177-382
```

Exactly the same as before and also a string, when I feed this into the earlier code:

```
total_A = open(Input_file_A,'r')
Data_input_file_A = total_A.readlines()
y = Data_input_file_A[7]
count = 0
with open(Input_file_B) as f:
    for line in f:
        count += line.count(y)
    print count
```

Result:
    Number of times: 0

How is this possible, please help me out!?

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` does not remove the newline character. This should be clear if instead of `print y` you do `repr (y)` to reveal all the characters. So in your code you need:

```
y = Data_input_file_A[7].rstrip()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly the problem. It works perfect now!